# How to configure mod_perl files in apache , i mean where to put them?

Tags: configuration, filter, mod-perl

There lots of tutorials on the web on how to configure the mod_perl filters 
but info i didn't understand and its like no where written , where to put them
and how to tell mod_perl/apache about there path /location .
i mean only the filters part not the ordinary perl files

Answer (score 0):

Filters like any other handlers just need to be in the INC path. Apache looks at the @INC path for any defined filter/handler modules defined. If you have it elsewhere, you could add path of your filter's to @INC through startup file or conf file to let apache know where to look for them before defining them using directives.